# Reward shaping experiments - interpreting results

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I've been training some agents playing Tetris, and I have ran some experiments with different reward structures:

[image]

I'm mostly interested in the potential-based rewards agent. I'm looking for some guidance on how to interpret that learning curve? It looks like its taking big steps at ~12000 and ~22000 epochs, and it's kind of shaped like a staircase. What could this signify about my agents learning?